# Spring @Scheduled set max execution time for task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring application with `@EnableScheduling` config and a method annotated with `@Scheduled (fixedDelay)`.

I faced a problem with a never ending task, it was probably connected to a DB connection failure but unfortunaly I could not clearly find the cause.

**How can I define a maximum runtime for `@Scheduled (fixedDelay)` job?** Is there any wait but running another parallel task thanks checks the duration?